# Using this parent in an if statement jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, this

Im trying to trigger the click on the parent div only on the parents that have the checkboxes inside them checked. I cant use 'this' because that makes '.choose-plain' trigger a click on it. is there a way to use this for the element in the if statement not the click?

```
$('.choose-plain').click(function(){
    if ($('.option-other').is(':checked')) {
        $(the parent div of the if statement only if .option-other is checked).trigger( "click" );
    } 
});
```

html/php

```
    <div id="special_feature_select" class="option_container choose choose-plain">
        <h5>Plain</h5>
        <img src="/img/decor/swatch/white.png"/>
        <?= $form->input('',array('name' => 'data[Pattern][plain]','value' => 1,'class' => 'option_value option-plain', 'type' => 'checkbox',
     'label' => false,'checked' => $pattern==1?'checked':false,'div' => false));?>
    </div>

    <div id="special_feature_select" class="option_container choose choose-other">
    <h5>Patterned</h5>
        <img src="/img/decor/swatch/patterned.png"/>
        <?= $form->input('',array('name' => 'data[Pattern][patterned]','value' => 254,'class' => 'option_value option-other', 'type' => 'checkbox',
     'label' => false,'checked' => $pattern==254?'checked':false,'div' => false));?>
    </div>

    <div id="special_feature_select" class="option_container choose choose-other">
        <h5>Childrens</h5>
        <img src="/img/decor/swatch/childrens.png"/>
        <?= $form->input('',array('name' => 'data[Pattern][childrens]','value' => 64,'class' => 'option_value option-other', 'type' => 'checkbox',
     'label' => false,'checked' => $pattern==64?'checked':false,'div' => false));?>
    </div>
```

because the checkboxes are hidden i have to trigger a click on the parent div, which in another part of my jquery triggers the box to check or uncheck.

Comment: post your html code.

Comment: How about `$('.option-other:checked').parent().click();` ?

Comment: Use `parent()/closest()`. `$('.option-other').parent()` or `$('.option-other').closest('selector')`

Comment: @Banik ive put the html in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your markup you have a invalid markup as you have same IDs applied on multiple divs. ***IDs should be unique for each element***.

You can use this:

```
$('.choose-plain').click(function(){
     var chcked = $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked');
     $('.option-other').prop('checked', !chcked);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... just want choose-plain to un tick the other checkboxes, I'm not using IDs I'm using classes.

Comment: Now it clears the requirement, you have to use .prop() method.

Comment: @SamJones check this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Jai